# > does the size of an array decreases automatically after adding less no of elements?

Tags: java, arrays, resize

I am trying to add two string using char array but it is not working. Does array changes size? please help with this problem:

```
public class shift {

    String name = "piyush";

    public void appends(String lastnaem) {
        char a[] = new char[20];
        System.out.println(a.length);//printing lenth of array
        a = name.toCharArray();//lastnaem.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(a.length);//printing length of array after adding string
        char v[] = lastnaem.toCharArray();
        //  for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
        //      a[6+i]=v[i];
        //  }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        shift s = new shift();
        s.appends("verma");
    }
}
```

The output is:

> 20
>   6

Comment: Im not really sure what you're asking, but a regular array wont change size after its created

Comment: no, the length of an array does not change... but `a = name.toCharArray()` changes the array that `a` is referencing (changes `a` itself).

Answer (score 0):

No, the size of the array does not change. When you write `a = name.toCharArray()` you simply create a completely new array with a new size and assign it to `a`.
The array `a` points to changes and the new array `a` points to has a different length than the original one.